# Criação de app Cortana em Português não esta funcionando

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-phone, windows-10, cortana

Primeiramente criei o seguinte xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>

<VoiceCommands xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/voicecommands/1.2">
  <CommandSet xml:lang="pt-BR" Name="CommandSet_pt-BR">
    <AppName> App2 </AppName>
    <Example> Esse e um exemplo </Example>

    <Command Name="Dando Oi">
      <Example> testando Oi Aplicativo </Example>
      <ListenFor> testando oi aplicativo </ListenFor>
      <Feedback> Ok, vou te dar um ola</Feedback>
      <Navigate />
    </Command>


  </CommandSet>
</VoiceCommands>
```

Após essa criação, fui registrar o comando no App.xaml.cs, com o seguinte código:

```
 try
            {
                StorageFile vcd = await Package.Current.InstalledLocation.GetFileAsync(@"teste.xml");
                await VoiceCommandDefinitionManager.InstallCommandDefinitionsFromStorageFileAsync(vcd);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }
```

Juntamente:

```
    protected async override void OnActivated(IActivatedEventArgs args)
    {

        base.OnActivated(args);


        if(args.Kind ==  ActivationKind.VoiceCommand)
        {
            VoiceCommandActivatedEventArgs cmd = args as VoiceCommandActivatedEventArgs;
            SpeechRecognitionResult result = cmd.Result;


            string commander = result.RulePath[0];

            MessageDialog dialog = new MessageDialog("");

            switch(commander)
            {
                case "testando oi aplicativo":
                    dialog.Content = "Funcionou";
                    break;

                default:
                    break;

            }

           await dialog.ShowAsync();
        }
    }
```

Finalizando, executei em modo Release. Quando testo a cortana para meu código, ela só abre o navegador, como se o app não tivesse registrado o comando.

Comment: Para facilitar a ajuda poste o trecho do código correspondente e explique exatamente o que está tentando fazer.

Comment: Pronto, Feito :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A princípio não sei onde você registrou o `xml` com as configurações dos comandos para reconhecimento, mas caso tenha sido no `OnActivated` apesar do nome não é executado quando o aplicativo é 'ativado'

O procedimento para registrar o comando de voz coloquei no método `OnLaunched` conforme trecho abaixo:

```
protected override async void OnLaunched(LaunchActivatedEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        var vcd = await Package.Current.InstalledLocation.GetFileAsync(@"teste.xml");
        await VoiceCommandDefinitionManager.InstallCommandDefinitionsFromStorageFileAsync(vcd);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    }
    ...
```

No arquivo `xml`fiz algumas mudanças, veja como ficou:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<VoiceCommands xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/voicecommands/1.2">
  <CommandSet xml:lang="pt-BR" Name="CommandSet_pt-BR">
    <CommandPrefix> Aplicativo, </CommandPrefix>
    <Example> Dizendo olá </Example>
    <Command Name="Dando Oi">
      <Example> diga olá </Example>
      <ListenFor> diga olá </ListenFor>
      <Feedback> Ok, vou te dar um ola</Feedback>
      <Navigate/>
    </Command>

  </CommandSet>
</VoiceCommands>
```

> Método `OnActivated`

```
protected override async void OnActivated(IActivatedEventArgs e)
{

    if (e.Kind != ActivationKind.VoiceCommand) return;
    var cmd = e as VoiceCommandActivatedEventArgs;
    var result = cmd?.Result;


    var commander = result?.RulePath[0];

    var dialog = new MessageDialog("");

    switch (commander)
    {
        case "testando oi aplicativo":
            dialog.Content = "Funcionou";
            break;
    }

    await dialog.ShowAsync();
    Debug.WriteLine("teste");
}
```

Testei no modo `debug` e `release` o comando para chamar a corta e os resultados:

> Comando de voz: Ei cortana, aplicativo diga olá

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Só falta um ajuste na comparação com `case "testando oi aplicativo":`